# Topic models evaluation in Gensim

Tags: lda, gensim

I've been experimenting with LDA topic modelling using [Gensim](http://radimrehurek.com/gensim/). I couldn't seem to find any topic model evaluation facility in Gensim, which could report on the perplexity of a topic model on held-out evaluation texts thus facilitates subsequent fine tuning of LDA parameters (e.g. number of topics). It would be greatly appreciated if anyone could shed some light on how I can perform topic model evaluation in Gensim. This question has also been posted on [metaoptimize](http://metaoptimize.com/qa/questions/14332/topic-models-evaluation-in-gensim).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the [answer](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gensim/LM619SB57zM) on the [gensim mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/gensim).

In short, the bound() method of LdaModel computes a lower bound on perplexity, based on a held-out corpus.

Comment: As of gensim 0.8.9, you can also use `model.log_perplexity(heldout)`, which is a convenience wrapper.